# Docker Postgres Ruby on Rails unable to connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker

I am following this tutorial from docker [Docker Rails](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#connect-the-database) and I have created a folder and added this code below in my docker file.

```
 FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
```

And my docker compose file code is:

```
 version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - .data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I am following tutorial when I am running docker compose up I can just see this error:

```
Could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What is wrong here I don't know how to inspect and detect error how to fix this.

Answer (score 7):

You need environment variables within your `web` container so that it knows how to connect to the `db` container.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGUSER=postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: when I changed   - .data:/var/lib/postgresql/data to - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data it solved my problem. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your `database.yml`  and add host set to `db` , then username and password and run the command again.